# Проблема с запросом к бд при нескольких параметрах

Tags: php, silex

Есть запрос в базу данных. И он работает.

```
$user = $GLOBALS['app']['db']->fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM lusers WHERE login = ?", array($login));
```

Но если я захочу сделать 2 параметра, он стабильно возвращает мне FALSE.
Подскажите, как задать несколько параметров.

**UPD**

```
$photo = $GLOBALS['app']['db']->fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM photo WHERE author = ? AND name = ?", array($authorID, $name));
```

Пробовал множество вариаций, это изначальная.

Comment: ну дак где, который не работает?

Comment: А сами догадайтесь!

Comment: Терпение добродетель. Сам я не знаток этого яп (препод уперся рогами и на других яп не принимает), но чую, что косяк банален и принципиально не там где я искал.

Comment: Посмотрите что принимает fetchAssoc вторым аргументом, я думаю это неправильно - array($authorID, $name)